# My old Crown Vic will not hold coolant. It runs straight through. Can't get to mechanic til jan. 1st

Tags: ford, hose, crown-victoria

I just want to know if I can use my car only for emergencies up until I can get it checked on 1 January.  If it is going to be alright just sitting there, or do I need to run antifreeze through there every day???

Answer (score 6):

I know it sucks Lisa, but no you cannot drive it in that state or your engine will overheat and probably seize up, costing thousands to repair or replace. Don't even drive it to the mechanic, get it towed.

I know you say you can't get it to a mechanic, but I'm sure you can if you try. If it really is impossible somehow get someone who's handy with cars to have a look as it may be a simple problem which can be easily fixed, for example a hose that's come loose. But don't drive it or you'll be the one causing the emergency.

Comment: VERY VERY HELPFUL!!!!!   I 'll  peek around up under there and will not go anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

As GdD says, you can't drive it, at all, without coolant - it will overheat in a matter of minutes (if not less) and destroy your engine.

If it is just sitting there, it does not need to have coolant in, it can sit empty.

It's worth having a look underneath to see if you can see where the coolant is coming from - it may just be a loose or split hose that you could fix yourself (or get a mechanically-savvy friend to fix for you) rather than having to get it towed to a mechanic.

Comment: Thank you so much... I was just thinking of going to the store in the morning.  I'll get up under there with a flashlight, and check around my neighbors to see if someone can help me.  I am incredibly relieved that it is okay just sitting there... I won't touch it until I can get to the mechanic  (or figure it out myself).  I'll check the hoses per an internet diagram of the radiator and hoses.  I am soooo relieved that it is okay just to sit for a week or so....  so relieved